# ROS PATH and after Installation

Tags: ros, ros-package-path, setup.sh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello..
I have followed the instructions of installation but i don't understand what I am supposed to do with ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Can someone please tell me the steps to go forward..
As when i perform step 3. Creating a workspace -> after following other command when I try to run " . setup.sh " it says NO SUCH FILE.

Please don't give me the link to ROS package path as I am not able to get proper solution from there...it will grateful if you can reply here with the steps..

I am using ubuntu oneiric latest version.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12154/ros-path-and-after-installation/) by [dbs12](https://answers.ros.org/users/1469/dbs12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must run the command in the folder where you created that file. Assuming you created it in your home folder, try

```
source ~/setup.sh
```

(The dot `.` and the `source` command do the same thing)

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1